# SQL CASE statement for boolean values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following SQL stored procedure

```
@Text varchar(max),
@isArchived varchar(10)

SELECT *
  FROM [Table1] 
  WHERE [StringText] = @ AND [isArchived] = 

  (CASE 
        WHEN @isArchived = 'ALL' THEN ???
        WHEN @isArchived = 'Yes' THEN 1
        WHEN @isArchived = 'No' THEN  0
    END)
```

My problem is that isArchived is of type bit in the table, and on a web page I have a dropdownlist with three values for isArchived: ALL, Yes, No.

For `Yes` it is 1 (true), for `No` it is 0 (false) but not sure what to put in for this line: `WHEN @isArchived = 'ALL' THEN ???` ideally it would totally ignore the line `AND [isArchived] = @isArchived` but not sure what the syntax for that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to avoid filtering when `@isArchived = 'ALL'`, you can compare `[isArchived]` to itself (as long as the value can't be `NULL`):

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table1] 
WHERE [StringText] = @Text AND [isArchived] = (
  CASE 
    WHEN @isArchived = 'ALL' THEN [isArchived]
    WHEN @isArchived = 'Yes' THEN 1
    WHEN @isArchived = 'No' THEN  0
  END)
```

Note that this kind of conditional filtering can impact your execution plans, so you might want to investigate a different approach as discussed in this article:

http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Comment: Thanks. That did it :) I think it should be ok, it will be placed in a SSRS report.